# iTextSharp - corrupt PDF and document close error

Tags: asp.net, listview, pdf, itext

This is very close to working. Not sure why I am getting an error at document.Close() or why I am getting a corrupt pdf when I delete document.Close().

It seems to not be posting any info to the pdf.

The code:

Main page with the button the user clicks:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EventList.ascx.cs"     
Inherits="Objects_EventList" %>
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstvwEvents"    
OnItemDataBound="lstvwEvents_OnItemDataBound">

<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton BorderStyle="0" CssClass="submitbutton" runat="server" AlternateText="Get PDF" ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="btnGenerateReport" />
    <div class="eventtease" style="width: 249px;border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c06b;padding-right: 10px;padding-top: 10px;height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <h3 style="clear: both;border-top: 1px solid #c0c06b;padding-top: 10px;"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrlShortDate" /><br /><%# Eval("EventName").ToString().ToUpper() %><br />(<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrlTimes" />)</h3>
    <p class="eventdescription" style="font: normal normal normal 7.5pt/normal Arial, Sans-Serif;margin-top: 3px;">
        <%# Eval("Description") %>
    </p>
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkLearnMore" Text="LEARN MORE" CssClass="learnmore" Visible="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.IO;

public partial class Objects_EventList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
public string city;
public int showcount;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Load_Events();
    };
}

protected void Load_Events()
{
    EventsDataContext edc = new EventsDataContext();

    var events = (from e in edc.tblEvents_Cafes
                  where e.EventDateTime >= DateTime.Now && e.VenueCity.Trim() == city.Trim() && (e.VenueName.Contains("Café") || e.VenueName.Contains("Cafe") )
                  orderby e.EventDateTime
                  select new 
{
EventName = e.EventName,
EventDate = e.EventDate,
EventTime = e.EventTime,
Description = edc.tblEvents_Cafe_Descriptions.OrderBy(d =>  d.Priority).Where(d => d.Keywords.ToLower() == e.EventName.ToLower()).Select(d => d.Description).First(), // edc.tblEvents_Cafe_Descriptions.OrderBy(d => d.Priority).Where(d => d.Keywords.ToLower() == e.EventName.ToLower() || d.Keywords.ToLower().CompareTo(e.EventName.ToLower()) >= 0).Select(d => d.Description).First()
                  }).Take(showcount);

    lstvwEvents.DataSource = events;
    lstvwEvents.DataBind();
}

protected void lstvwEvents_OnItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var tempevent = dataItem.DataItem;
        Type t = tempevent.GetType();

        DateTime tempdate;

        if (DateTime.TryParse((t.GetProperty("EventDate").GetValue(tempevent,  null)).ToString(), out tempdate))
        {
            Literal ltrlShortDate = new Literal();
            ltrlShortDate = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrlShortDate");
            ltrlShortDate.Text = tempdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse((t.GetProperty("EventTime").GetValue(tempevent, null)).ToString(), out tempdate))
        {
            Literal ltrlTimes = new Literal();
            ltrlTimes = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrlTimes");
            ltrlTimes.Text = tempdate.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        }
    }
}


private void GeneratePDF(string path, string fileName, bool download, string text)
{

    var document = new Document();

    try {

        if (download) {

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

        } else {

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.Create));
        }

        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
        document.Open();

        if (text.Length.Equals(0)) {

        lstvwEvents.DataBind();
        using (StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter(strB)) {

            using (HtmlTextWriter htWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter)) {

                ListView lv1 = lstvwEvents;

                lv1.RenderControl(htWriter);
                                                                           }
                                                              }
            } else {

            strB.Append(text);
            }

        using (TextReader sReader = new StringReader(strB.ToString())) {

        List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sReader, new StyleSheet());

        foreach (IElement elm in list) {

            document.Add(elm);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ee) {

    ee.ToString();

} finally {

    document.Close();
}

}

protected void btnGenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string fileName = "Calendar.pdf";
    GeneratePDF("", fileName, true, "");

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
 }   

}
```

Comment: You're passing `True` as a third parameter but then you're writing directly to the `Response.OutputStream` which doesn't seem like the correct logic.

Comment: The corrupt document when omitting `Close()` is to be expected. The error on `Close()` could easily be *The Document has no pages.* Unfortunately, you're not telling us anything about the error message.